# how to rewrite query in sql to symfony with parenthesis

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I tried to write something like this:

```
 $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $subQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $subQuery->expr()->exists("SELECT r1.id
                                   FROM Entity\\Role r1
                                   LEFT JOIN u.roles
                                   WHERE r1.name = 'ROLE_A'");

        $subQuery2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $subQuery2->expr()->exists("SELECT r2.id
                               FROM Entity\\Role r2
                               LEFT JOIN u.roles
                               WHERE r2.name = 'ROLE_D'");

        $subQuery3 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $subQuery3->expr()->orX($subQuery->getDql(), $subQuery2->getDql());


        $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
            ->select('u')
            ->from('Entity\\User', 'u')
            ->from('Entity\\UserSeason', 'us')
            ->where('u.id = us.user')
            ->andWhere('us.season = :season')
            ->andWhere('us.department = :department')
            ->andWhere($subQuery3->getDql());
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('season', $season);
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('department', $department);
```

but it is not working... What I want is somethink like this:

```
        SELECT u
        FROM Entity\\User u
             Entity\\UserSeason us
        WHERE u = us.user
        AND us.season = :season
        AND us.department = :department
        AND (
           EXISTS SELECT r1.id
                   FROM Entity\\Role r1
                   LEFT JOIN u.roles
                   WHERE r1.name = 'ROLE_A'
            OR EXISTS SELECT r2.id
                       FROM Entity\\Role r2
                       LEFT JOIN u.roles
                       WHERE r2.name = 'ROLE_D'
        )
```

I tried some way but I can not find the right one...

Any ideas? Thanks